Hasura GraphQL error: "field '{name of mutation}' not found in type: 'mutation_root'" for table with insert only user permissions
I recently added a table in Hasura and I restricted the table to only have insert permissions at the user level since the user didn't need to perform any queries.
However, the mutation to insert into the table kept failing with the message "field 'insert_appraise_request_v2_one' not found in type: 'mutation_root'". The field in this case is the name of the automatically created Hasura insert mutation. However, I had no issues using the mutation in the hasura admin console.
export const INSERT_APPRAISE_REQUEST_V2 = gql`
  mutation InsertAppraiseRequestV2($object: appraise_request_v2_insert_input!) {
    insert_appraise_request_v2_one(object: $object) {
      id
    }
  }
`


The root cause was that I needed to grant the user select permissions as well since the mutation also returns specific fields (in this case id). Once I granted select permissions, the error resolved.

